# Expression:map/set iterator not incrementable

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator

When programm execute this private method

```
map<char*, vector<MAILPACK>>::iterator mit;
vector<MAILPACK>::iterator dit;
for(mit=funcs.begin(); mit!=funcs.end(); mit++) {
    TRACE tr;
    tr.crc32 = crc32;
    strncpy(tr.name, (*mit).first, sizeof(tr.name));
    int i = 0;
    for(dit=(*mit).second.begin(); dit!=(*mit).second.end(); dit++){
        tr.nodes[i++] = dit->dwAddr;
    }       
}
```

I get error like: `Expression:map/set iterator not incrementable`

This function iterate through private map `std::map<char*, std::vector<MAILPACK>> funcs;`

Where I'm wrong?
Thx

P.S. oh, I found that I didn't control boundaries when saving addresses into tr.nodes.
But this is not the point...

Comment: can you supply the header to the function or whatever defined funcs

Comment: If you think you might be scribbling over the end of your `tr.nodes`, and this is a runtime error, then you might be overwriting `mit`. Have you checked?

Comment: the way you implemented the inner for loop means that you start at tr.nodes[1] for dit.begin()->dwAddr; is that intentional?

Comment: @Moritz - no, that's a postincrement; increment and return the old value (or, conceptually, use the old value and then increment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some `typedef`'s wouldn't go astray. And *pre-increment* your iterators, avoiding useless iterator object copies.

```
typedef vector<MAILPACK> Mailpacks;
typedef map<char*, Mailpacks> MailpackMap;

for(MailpackMap::iterator mit=funcs.begin(); mit!=funcs.end(); ++mit) 
{
  TRACE tr;
  tr.crc32 = crc32;
  strncpy(tr.name, (*mit).first, sizeof(tr.name));
  int i = 0;
  Mailpacks& mail = (*mit).second;
  for(Mailpacks::iterator dit= mail.begin(); dit!=mail.end(); ++dit)
  {
    tr.nodes[i++] = dit->dwAddr;
  }       
}
```

I agree with @Chowlett, and think you're stomping out of your `tr.nodes` bounds and over one of your iterators. Since you are instantiating your `TRACE` object during the loop, there is a good chance this is happening. You will usually get the `Expression:map/set iterator not incrementable` error when your **iterator has been *invalidated***.

Is there any reason you're `tr.nodes` member can't be a vector too?

```
tr.nodes.push_back(dit->dwAddr);
```

I could be wrong, more information always helps.

Comment: `auto` is a storage class specifier, not to be used to implicitly infer the type in C++03 or less and its not tagged C++11.

Comment: While true, we don't know he _can't_ use C++11. It's not like it's a completely new language. Until recently, I'd barely registered that my compiler supported a bunch of (and not all of!) C++11 features.

Comment: Ok Yes I apologise for that. I'll make amendments.

Comment: @Chowlett By now many people make the simple assumption that C++11 is enabled. It makes the examples easier to write and shows beginners The Way (tm). As long as the code is easy to port back, no harm is done. More intrusive features shouldn't be used extensively, of course.